# SQL Server 2014 Wrong result in Where clause, help me to understand why

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I read online that specifically a where clause like this:

> where Location2 <> ''

should evaluate to true for a column value of Null.

This behavior is consistently not working for me in SQL Server 2014.  That where clause will exclude my Null columns.  We can write a query to overcome this, but I need to know what to expect and if this is a new behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: No, `NULL` is neither equal nor unequal to anything else(including `NULL`) with [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=sql.120).aspx) set to ON.

Comment: where did you read that?, because that is "undetermined", not true

Comment: Null comparisons are complicated -- the results depend, among other things, on the ANSI compatibility flags you've got enabled on your database. Best not to rely on them, and add an IS NULL check as others have suggested.

Comment: It seems my premise was wrong and the article I read says what you all are saying - I must have read it wrong or not waited long enough for my coffee to kick in.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the value of [ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE
> column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in
> column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL
> returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
> comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT
> statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that
> have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE
> column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the
> column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <>
> XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not
> NULL.

Presumably you are operating with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`.  As the docs say, NULL means "unknown", and any operation that deals with unknown values is also unknown.

If you want to compare directly with NULL, you can set `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` immediately before your query and turn it back on afterwards.  For example:

```
declare @x varchar(10)

set ansi_nulls on
if @x <> '' select 'yes' else select 'no' -- returns "no"

set ansi_nulls off
if @x <> '' select 'yes' else select 'no' -- returns "yes"
```

A better option is to explicitly do comparisons with `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, and `ISNULL()`.  For example, you could use ISNULL to simplify comparisons like this:

```
declare @x varchar(10)

set ansi_nulls on
if isnull(@x, '') <> '' select 'yes' else select 'no' -- returns "no"

set ansi_nulls off
if isnull(@x, '') <> '' select 'yes' else select 'no' -- returns "no"
```

If you are curious whether the ANSI_NULLS is enabled during execution, you could check the [@@OPTIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177525.aspx) bit 32:

```
if @@OPTIONS & 32 = 32
    select 'ANSI_NULLS is ON'
else
    select 'ANSI_NULLS is OFF'
```

Answer (score 3):

Null compared with anything, anyway, is not true, always fails, check this:

```
NULL = NULL -- fails
NULL <> '' -- fails: can be translated as "it's not different to '' "
NULL = '' -- fails: can be translated as "it's not equal to '' ", surprised?
```

you should use

```
where Location2 <> '' or Location2 is null
```

ADDED: (er... copied & pasted from @Bacon Bits comment below, thanks)

Actually, the truth value for all those expressions is UNKNOWN. The complexity comes when combining UNKNOWN with AND and OR. UNKNOWN kind of behaves like FALSE, but it's kind of an odd duck. The bottom line: Always handle your NULLS.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` is not false - trivially observable by evaluating `NOT (NULL = NULL)`. It's the third truth value of SQL's three-valued logic - `UNKNOWN`

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the Null = Null, that is very interesting.

Comment: Actually, the truth value for all those expressions is UNKNOWN.  The complexity comes when combining UNKNOWN with AND and OR.  UNKNOWN *kind of* behaves like FALSE, but it's kind of an odd duck.  The bottom line: Always handle your NULLS.